# How to create a clickable(initializing unclicked) adapter for ArrayList<Integer> in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I want to create an adapter for RecyclerView, which is clickable just like radio buttons in a radio group.
I tried using ArrayList, but I don't know how to make it initialize the rest when one is clicked.
I want to set text color blue when it is clicked, and gray when it is not clicked.

How can I make it possible?

```
public class AdapterHoleTitle extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterHoleTitle.ViewHolder> {
private final Activity context;

public AdapterHoleTitle(Activity _context) {
    this.context = _context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lsv_item_hole_title, viewGroup, false);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(
            v -> {
                // want to make an OnClickListener here
            }
    );

    return new AdapterHoleTitle.ViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    ArrayList<Integer> tt = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j=1; j<=9; j++) {
        tt.add(j);
    }
    viewHolder.holeName.setText(tt.get(i)+"hole");
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 9;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView holeName;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        holeName = v.findViewById(R.id.holeName);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: hi ! your lsv_item_hole_title.xml must contains a radiobutton instead of a textview.

Comment: @SebastienRieu Isn't it not possible to affect other radiobuttons' status if they are not grouped in the same radio group?